# Install App in Office 365 online

Tags: office365-apps

I'm trying to install an App from the [Office Store](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/store) in Office 365 Home Premium, specifically the *online* version accessed via OneDrive. Example of such an App would be [Modern Trend](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/store/modern-trend-WA104220390.aspx?redir=0) for Excel. The [documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/office-store-faq-HA102900784.aspx) says click Insert > My Apps, but I don't find this menu option in the online Excel.

Can Apps be installed in the online version of Office? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt your question is suitable for SO as it seems you're asking about how to install an already made application as opposed to developing said applications.

In the event I'm incorrect...

Apparently not; that doesn't surprise me though. Also, notice the link you provided doesn't specify that it pertains to any of the online versions of mentioned programs.

I opened my account, created a blank worksheet, and tried to add an app. First thing to notice is that the ribbon is limited online. It doesn't even have the "Apps" section as shown in the link. So I proceeded to "open in Excel", which will open the file on your local machine. Yahtzee, I'm able to add the app.

Perhaps you should try adding the app at "home" and after opening the file online and see if the app is functional. Problem would be solved.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Your suggestion worked. To be specific, here is what I did: (i) created a spreadsheet with the Store App on a Windows machine running Office 2013, (ii) saved the spreadsheet to OneDrive, (iii) opened using Excel app for iPad, & Excel web app in Firefox/Linux. Result the app worked fine on Firefox/Linux, but on the iPad app I got only an image (picture) of the app. Maybe I'm missing something, but your suggestion worked. Let us see if there are further comments, meanwhile I have marked your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Microsoft currently has this feature on their development roadmap:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/products/office-365-roadmap-FX104343353.aspx